# Audio problems, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have lost the audio on my system running Ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT: After reboot, the sound seems to work after I log out and in again.

Have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
sudo alsa force-reload
reboot

sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
sudo apt-get install pulseeffects
```

`aplay -l` returns:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Observation: I have to run `pulseaudio --start` before I can run `pavucontrol` successfully. After `pavucontrol` I can find audio cards in sound settings, but not before. Have unmuted everything in `alsamixer`.
The audio worked before but I was fiddling with keyboard controls and lost it.
Sound works in windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Jarle

Comment: I have exactly the same problem from today. No update was running before. Jarle, do you find some solution?

Comment: In syslog I find this error message:
Jun  2 18:21:44 lipa pulseaudio[3705]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Sorry, I did not find the cause of the problem. I did a reinstall of audio controls, and now audio works, but after a reboot, I have to log in and out before audio works.

Comment: I try reinstallation too, but did not help. Last think what I did was start "Totem movie player" switch to Setting -> Sound -> Applications and in application select this appplication (Totem) and mute next unmute checkbox. After this action it works again. I do not understand what happens, but it works.